# Syntax highlighting issue on multiline code in Sublime Text 3 (Ruby on Rails & Haml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext3, haml, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting in my html.haml view fails when I break up my code on several lines:

Example: 
Syntax highlighting working on single line:

```
  = link_to results_path(keyword), remote: true, rel: 'tooltip', title: 'Voir les résultats Google' do
    %i.icon-external-link
```

But on multiple lines, syntax highlighting only works on the first one:

```
  = link_to results_path(keyword), remote: true,
      rel: 'tooltip', title: 'Voir les résultats Google' do
    %i.icon-external-link
```

[what I get: no syntax highlighting on "child" lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIQEp.png)

[what I would expect: syntax highlighting even on child lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyD3m.png)

Here are the packages I have installed referring to syntax highlighting & code display:

- ApplySyntax
- Haml
- +Ruby on Rails snippets

Comment: You could use a pipe character `|` to designate [multiline](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#multiline) code. The code works, but unfortunately Sublime doesn't highlight it.

Comment: Indeed the code works perfectly, and it is better organized on several lines.
The thing is that it becomes hard to distinguish different elements without highlighting in the "child lines" code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This https://github.com/iRet/sublime-haml fixes the issue for me (Sublime 3). After installation, just select `Ruby Haml` (the root list with syntax options) instead of `Rails -> Ruby Haml`.

Comment: Thank you Kamen !
I checked a few files and it seems to do the trick :). I will try it !
However on the first page I checked I noticed another highlighting bug :/ but it's another story...